# Include all .d.ts but exclude .ts on glob for gulp.src

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob, minimatch

## Background

After I compile my Typescript files on my Angular2 project, I will have the following directory structure (simplified):

```
├── app
│   └── app.module.d.ts
│   └── app.module.js
│   └── app.module.ts
│   └── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
│   └── index.ts
│   └── sample.component.d.ts
│   └── sample.component.js
│   └── sample.component.ts
│   └── sample.component.html
│   └── sample.component.css
```

## Problem

Using `gulp@3.9.1` and `gulp.src()`, how can I create a glob array which will include all the files under the `app` folder, but ignoring the `.ts` files corresponding to their `.d.ts` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way in your case, is to be explicit in what you want to include.

Working example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('app/**/*.*(js|html|css|d.ts)').pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});
```

Result:

```
$ tree out
out
├── app.module.d.ts
├── app.module.js
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── sample.component.css
├── sample.component.d.ts
├── sample.component.html
└── sample.component.js

0 directories, 8 files
```

See the documentation on gulp glob options here:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options

Which inherently uses `node-gulp` patterns, documented here:
https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Comment: This does not solve my problem as I do not want to ignore any file ending in `.d.ts`.

Comment: I misunderstood the requirements and have updated my answer to reflect.